# In SAS how to compute area under the curve

Tags: sas

I want to computed area under the curve in SAS using following data:

```
MeasNo  X   Y    ASN
1   10  20        1
2   12  22        1
3   13  21        1
4   14  25        1
5   11  18        1
6   15  21        1
7   13  19        1
8   12  22        1
9   11  18        1
10  10  22        1
1   11  21        2
2   13  24        2
3   12  22        2
4   15  24        2
5   12  19        2
6   14  20        2
7   111 18        2
8   14  25        2
9   13  20        2
10  10  21        2
```

I tried this way..

```
data work.forArea; 
 set WORK.myData; 

 Lag_X=lag(X);
 Lag_Y=lag(Y);

 xDiff = X - Lag_X;  /* width of rectangle */
 areaRect = xDiff * (Y + Lag_Y)/2; /* multiply width by mean of height of two consecutive measurement (rectangles)*/ 

if first.MeasNo /*consecutive measurements */
    then do; /* There is no rectangle for a subject’s first... */ 
        Lag_X = .; /* ...data point alone. Be sure not to use the... */ 
        Lag_Y = .; /* ...last data point from the previous rect. */ 
        xDiff = .; 
        areaRect = .; 
    end; 
 run;
```

I didn't get the result as expected. When MeasNo = 1, the Lag of X and Y should reset, instead of remaining consicuting to the previous value of X and Y at MeasNo=10.

Could someone please help?

I also tried the below, which worked...

```
 data work.forArea3; 
 set WORK.forArea4; 
 if ( _N_ = 1) then do;
   variable=0;
   Lag_Y=0;
   Lag_X=0;
   xDiff=0;  
   areaRect=0; 
 end;
 run;
```

But the code below did not work...

```
 data work.forArea5; 
  set WORK.forArea3; 
 if (ASN NE lag1(ASN) and MeasNo=1) then do;
     Lag_Y=0;
     Lag_X=0;
     xDiff = 0; 
     areaRect = 0; 
   end; else do;
 if (ASN = lag1(ASN) and MeasNo>=2) then do;
    Lag_Y=lag1(Y);
     Lag_X=lag1(X);
     xDiff = X - Lag_X; 
     areaRect = xDiff * (Y + Lag_Y)/2;
  end; else do;
 end;
 end;
 run;
```

Comment: Try `_N_ = 1` instead of `first.MeasNo`.

Comment: Try `if MeasNo=1` instead of `first.MeasNo`. But also look into using proc logistic to compute AUC.

Comment: Thanks Robert and @Quentin.. No I do not want to use proc logistic, my requirements are a bit different, I am sorry I can't write here.

Comment: @RobertSoszyński it works well for the first row. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your logic, but if what you want is for the first record of each ASN group to have missing Area, I think below will do it.

I usually compute the lags outside of the conditional block, and then use them conditionally.

Note that there are negative areas because both x sometimes decreases.  Perhaps you want to add ABS() function to compute absolute value in the computation of xDiff.

If this isn't your desired output, please add it to your question.

```
92   data work.forArea;
93    set WORK.myData;
94    by ASN;
95
96    Lag_X=lag(X);
97    Lag_Y=lag(Y);
98
99    if first.ASN=0
100      then do;
101        xDiff = X - Lag_X;
102        areaRect = xDiff * (Y + Lag_Y)/2;
103      end;
104   put (ASN X Y areaRect)(=);
105  run;

ASN=1 X=10 Y=20 areaRect=.
ASN=1 X=12 Y=22 areaRect=42
ASN=1 X=13 Y=21 areaRect=21.5
ASN=1 X=14 Y=25 areaRect=23
ASN=1 X=11 Y=18 areaRect=-64.5
ASN=1 X=15 Y=21 areaRect=78
ASN=1 X=13 Y=19 areaRect=-40
ASN=1 X=12 Y=22 areaRect=-20.5
ASN=1 X=11 Y=18 areaRect=-20
ASN=1 X=10 Y=22 areaRect=-20
ASN=2 X=11 Y=21 areaRect=.
ASN=2 X=13 Y=24 areaRect=45
ASN=2 X=12 Y=22 areaRect=-23
ASN=2 X=15 Y=24 areaRect=69
ASN=2 X=12 Y=19 areaRect=-64.5
ASN=2 X=14 Y=20 areaRect=39
ASN=2 X=111 Y=18 areaRect=1843
ASN=2 X=14 Y=25 areaRect=-2085.5
ASN=2 X=13 Y=20 areaRect=-22.5
ASN=2 X=10 Y=21 areaRect=-61.5
```